# Python - reading between parenthesis as a single 'block'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a program in Python which does various tasks to a piece of code. I have done most of these, but one is perplexing me. I don't know enough of the jargon to be able to run an effective search for help with this problem, so I am resorting to asking here.

I need to create a process which reads anything in between parentheses as a single 'block'. Then, if a 'block' contains a specific word or phrase, the python code would delete it.

Example (simplified) Text File contents:

```
...
entity
{
    "id" "38794"
    "classname" "info_player_teamspawn"
}
entity
{
    "id" "38795"
    "classname" "func_detail"
    solid
}
entity
{
    "id" "38796"
    "classname" "path_track"
}
...
```

In this example, there would be many thousands of these entities listed. I would want the python code to delete anything inside parentheses (and including the 'entity' preface) of any parentheses which contained the word 'solid', ie:
This would be the resulting piece:

```
...
entity
{
    "id" "38794"
    "classname" "info_player_teamspawn"
}
entity
{
    "id" "38796"
    "classname" "path_track"
}
...
```

The id would not need to be corrected. We do not need to worry about that.

I hope I explained my problem well enough, and I hope there is a solution possible. If anyone would like to a library of jargon I could use to help explain or research any further problems I may have, that would be appreciated too!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: May the braces be arbitrary nested? If not; look for `re.sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's write a generator that yields titles ("entity") and their respective blocks:

```
def blocks(filename):
    title, block = '', None
    with open(filename) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if '{' in line:
                block = line
            elif block is not None:
                block += line
            else:
                title = line
            if '}' in line:
                yield title, block
                title, block = '', None
```

Then read the blocks and output those passing the test:

```
for title, block in blocks('input.txt'):
    if 'solid' not in block:
        print title, block
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do everything using a single regular expression. However, that quickly becomes unreadable, expecially as you span multiple lines (and I guess you may have other patterns you might want to remove).

I would split the problem in two:

First, find all the entity blocks using this regular expression:

```
p = re.compile(r'entity\s*{(.*?)}')
```

Then define a substitute function that does the replacement.

```
def remove_solid(match):
    text = match.groups(0)
    if text.find('solid') != -1:
        return ''
    else
        return text
```

Hook these two together like this

```
output = p.sub(remove_solid, input)
```

Comment: +1 for splitting the problem. You need `re.S` to match multiple lines and return the full `match.group()` (not only `text`), [example](http://ideone.com/B7toq). Also use `'solid' in text` instead of `text.find('solid') != -1`

Comment: You are right that I need `re.S`. I tend to answer using code snippets and fragments, as my purpose is not to provide working code, but to point people in the right direction. I thought `match.group(0)` and `match.group()` to be equivalent, but maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: compare .group in my example vs. .groups in you code that returns a tuple. Also `()` are unnecessary in this case. The advantage of Python that it is an *executable* pseudo-code i.e., you can test it.

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian, testing the code would defeat my purpose, which is to point people in the right _direction_. If people want me to write their code for them, they will have to pay me. Since OP has not bothered to accept the answer, I don't think he will give me money;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expressions (regex) to search for the following pattern and replace matched text with line break or space.

```
import re

[...]
output = re.sub(r'entity\n{[\w\s\n"]*solid[\w\s\n"]*\n}\n', '', input)
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
 re.sub("entity\s*{[^}]*solid\s*}",'',yourString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex solution. It might be a little more verbose, but also more intuitive.

```
input = open("a.txt", "rb")
output = open("b.txt", "wb") # an empty file for output

def filter_block(instream, outstream, keyword):
    block_buffer = []
    in_block = False
    dump_block = False
    for line in instream:                 # <- Iterate through the lines of the input
        line = line.rstrip()
        block_buffer.append(line)         # <- Keep the block of text in memory

        line_text = line.strip()
        if line_text == "{":
            in_block = True
        elif line_text == keyword and in_block:            # <- Check if this block
            dump_block = True                              #    needs to be dumped
        elif line_text == "}":
            if not dump_block:                             # <- If not, 
                outstream.write("\n".join(block_buffer))   # <- keep it.
                #print "\n".join(block_buffer)

            block_buffer = []                              # <- Flush buffer, continue
            in_block = dump_block = False



filter_block(input, output, "solid")
```